# parse byteBuf cbor and ProtobufSchemaLoader.std.parse

Tags: java

I have byteBuf and I need to parse with two options: (in java)

1. cbor
2. `ProtobufSchemaLoader.std.parse(protobuf_str)`, how I can create protobuf_str so I can read this buf.

the classes that I have is:

```
public class Payload {
    Map<Date, Data> dataArray;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Payload [dataArray=" + dataArray + "]";
    }

    public Map<Date, Data> getDataArray() {
        return dataArray;
    }

    public void setDataArray(Map<Date, Data> dataArray) {
        this.dataArray = dataArray;
    }
    
    
}

public class Data {
    private Map<Integer, Object > data;
    
    public Map<Integer, Object> getDataArray() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setDataArray(Map<Integer, Object> dataArray) {
        this.data = dataArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your question, can you show example what are you trying to achieve ? and what did you try so far and what errors did you get ?

Comment: i have byte[] msgByte, i want to read and convert this msg with CBOR to Payload object